# Facebook API: publish_stream permission works only once

Tags: facebook

I am working on one application based on Web to post on the wall, comment, like and delete post through the API of Facebook. I ask for these permissions in the register step:

```
***'scope' => 'publish_actions,read_stream,publish_stream'***
```

and after registration I can do everything: Post on the wall, comment a post, like and delete. But once I logout from my application and then log in again, take the proper token from my database and try to do the same things, I find that I can post on the wall and delete post but when I try to like or comment I found this error:

> ***Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: (#200) Requires publish_stream permission or Requires extended permission:
>   publish_actions thrown in...***.

But in fact when I asked about the permission of the user to facebook I have this answer:

```
*Array ( [data] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [installed] => 1 [read_stream] => 1 [status_update] => 1 [photo_upload] => 1 [video_upload] => 1 [create_note] => 1 [share_item] => 1 [publish_stream] => 1 [publish_actions] => 1 ) ) )*
```

What I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Could you clean up your question a bit - it's not clear what API you're using - are you sure the user hasn't revoked permissions?

Comment: @Igy I am using php/sdk and I am sure the user hasn´t revoked permissions. What I try to do is store the token in database so that the next time the user login in my application is not necessary to ask for permission again or register (only the first time he use my application), he could post, comment and so on from my application. What I don´t understand is why is working fine "post" and "delete" and not "comment" and "like". Moreover facebook said that I have the correct permission.

Answer (score 0):

When the user logs into facebook again, you should refresh their token in your database and use the updated version with any API calls you make.

Comment: Yes I thought about it @NirajShah and that is one solution to my problem, allways the user log in use the function "getLoginUrl()". But I would like to avoid the user has to sign in (on Facebook) all times he wants to use my application. My goal is to use the tokens directly from database until it expires. All the functionalities are working fine with this model, but not "comment" and "like". Any idea? Thanks!